# How to output Database table in the dashboard body in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I output the result of a database query into my shiny app dashboard. Here's my code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dbConnect)
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
library(foreign)

conn <- dbConnect(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    dbname = "shinytest",
    host = "localhost",
    username = "root",
    password = "root")

rs <- dbGetQuery(conn, "Select * from test;") 

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody())

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now the code `rs <- dbGetQuery(conn, "Select * from test")` does give the output in the console window but I want to output it in the dashboard body.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try shiny documentation eg https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dbConnect)
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
library(foreign)

dbDisconnect(conn)
conn <- dbConnect(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    dbname = "apilogs",
    host = "localhost",
    username = "root",
    password = "root")

rs <- dbGetQuery(conn, "Select * from test;") 

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(box(

tableOutput('table')
)))


server <- function(input, output) {
output$table <- renderTable(rs)

}

dbDisconnect(conn)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```